# Why am I seeing a difference in copy times between these two implementations?

Tags: c#, .net, io, copy

I have written an application that implements a file copy that is written as below. I was wondering why, when attempting to copy from a network drive to a another network drive, the copy times are huge (20-30 mins to copy a 300mb file) with the following code:

```
 public static void CopyFileToDestination(string source, string dest)
    {
        _log.Debug(string.Format("Copying file {0} to {1}", source, dest));
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        string destinationFolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(dest);
        if (!Directory.Exists(destinationFolderPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationFolderPath);
        }
        if (File.Exists(dest))
        {
            File.Delete(dest);
        }

        FileInfo sourceFile = new FileInfo(source);
        if (!sourceFile.Exists)
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("source = " + source);
        }

        long totalBytesToTransfer = sourceFile.Length;

        if (!CheckForFreeDiskSpace(dest, totalBytesToTransfer))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Unable to copy file {0}: Not enough disk space on drive {1}.",
                source, dest.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()));
        }

        long bytesTransferred = 0;

        using (FileStream reader = sourceFile.OpenRead())
        {
            using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                byte[] buf = new byte[64 * 1024];
                int bytesRead = reader.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                double lastPercentage = 0;
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    double percentage = ((float)bytesTransferred / (float)totalBytesToTransfer) * 100.0;
                    writer.Write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesTransferred += bytesRead;
                    if (Math.Abs(lastPercentage - percentage) > 0.25)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : Copied {1:#,##0} of {2:#,##0} MB ({3:0.0}%)",
                            sourceFile.Name,
                            bytesTransferred / (1024 * 1024),
                            totalBytesToTransfer / (1024 * 1024),
                            percentage));
                        lastPercentage = percentage;
                    }
                    bytesRead = reader.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : Done copying", sourceFile.Name));
        _log.Debug(string.Format("{0} copied in {1:#,##0} seconds", sourceFile.Name, (DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds));
    }
```

However, with a simple File.Copy, the time is as expected.

Does anyone have any insight? Could it be because we are making the copy in small chunks?

Comment: `Could it be because we are making the copy in small chunks?` -- That hypothesis would be easy enough to test.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thats what I am trying right now... but I wanted to know if someone had insight right off the bat.

Comment: Let us know what the outcome of the test is.

Comment: 64K chunks are *not* small with regard to network exchange. Perhaps it may help to use a profiler to figure out which routine consumes the most time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry it has taken so long to respond. I was sidetracked. I bumped up the block size and it seems to have sped things up slightly. I also have a attributed some of the slow down to network issues. I will also try some of the items Jim Mischel described below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the size of your `buf` variable doesn't change the size of the buffer that `FileStream.Read` or `FileStream.Write` use when communicating with the file system. To see any change with buffer size, you have to specify the buffer size when you open the file.

As I recall, the default buffer size is 4K. Performance testing I did some time ago showed that the sweet spot is somewhere between 64K and 256K, with 64K being more consistently the best choice.

You should change your `File.OpenRead()` to:

```
new FileStream(sourceFile.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, BufferSize)
```

Change the `FileShare` value if you don't want exclusive access, and declare `BufferSize` as a constant equal to whatever buffer size you want. I use `64*1024`.

Also, change the way you open your output file to:

```
new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, BufferSize)
```

Note that I used `FileMode.Create` rather than `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`. If you use `OpenOrCreate` and the source file is smaller than the existing destination file, I don't think the file is truncated when you're done writing. So the destination file would contain extraneous data.

That said, I wouldn't expect this to change your copy time from 20-30 minutes down to the few seconds that it should take. I suppose it could if every low-level read requires a network call. With the default 4K buffer, you're making 16 read calls to the file system in order to fill your 64K buffer. So by increasing your buffer size you greatly reduce the number of OS calls (and potentially the number of network transactions) your code makes.

Finally, there's no need to check to see if a file exists before you delete it. `File.Delete` silently ignores an attempt to delete a file that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Call the [SetLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setlength.aspx) method on your writer Stream before actual copying, this should reduce operations by the target disk.

Like so

```
writer.SetLength(totalBytesToTransfer);
```

You may need to set the Stream's psoition back to the start after calling this method by using Seek. Check the position of the stream after calling SetLength, should be still zero.

```
writer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // Not sure on that one
```

If that still is too slow use the [SetFileValidData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)